# Stop validating audience for webapi application in Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET WEB API Core 3.1 application working with Azure AD. 
I use *Microsoft.Identity.Web* library. 
I set up it like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    Trace.TraceInformation("Configuring services");
    services.AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration, subscribeToJwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents: true
            )
        .AddProtectedWebApiCallsProtectedWebApi(Configuration)
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
.......
}
```

My application is multi-tenant, so I need to cancel validating audience.
Recently I've used the library as a separate project, so I could change it in its source code:

```
ValidateIssuer = false
```

but currently I use the library from nuget, so I can't simply change the source code to avoid validation of audience (issuer).

How should I configure the library to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a multitenant application, set `ValidateIssuer` to `false`. That means the application will validate the issuer. Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/web-api#authenticating-in-the-web-api).

Validate the token issuer in the `JwtBearerEvents.TokenValidated` event. The issuer is sent in the "iss" claim.

It is possible to disable issuer validation, you could refer to the code as below:

```
public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
{
    options.Audience = AzureOptions.ClientId;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters{
        ValidateIssuer = false
    };
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
        {
            if(!context.SecurityToken.Issuer.StartsWith("https://sts.windows.net/"))
                throw new SecurityTokenValidationException();
                return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };

    options.Authority = $"{AzureOptions.Instance}{AzureOptions.TenantId}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can Inject your own validation code to handle multitenant validation, instead of trying to disable the validation. 
something like

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options => {
options.Authority += "/v2.0";

// The web API accepts as audiences both the Client ID (options.Audience) and api://{ClientID}.
options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new []
{
 options.Audience,
 $"api://{options.Audience}"
};

// Instead of using the default validation (validating against a single tenant,
// as we do in line-of-business apps),
// we inject our own multitenant validation logic (which even accepts both v1 and v2 tokens).
options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = AadIssuerValidator.GetIssuerValidator(options.Authority).Validate;; });
```

As per microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration#code-initialization

Answer (score 1):

By using **Microsoft.Identity.Web** library, **ValidateIssuer** can be set to false as shown below:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddProtectedWebApi(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
},options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); });
```

The Access Token contains **aud** (Audience) and **iss** (Issuer) as two separate claims.

Audience is the intended recipient of the token. The audience is Application ID of the API assigned in the Azure portal and **to stop validating audience** is not recommended.